# CustomView code doesn't show in spite of no error

Tags: swift

I'm making UI circle and want to support **CustomView.swift** was added on my xcode.

This is latest swift in the Xcode

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        oval1()
        oval2()
    }

    func oval1() {
        /// [marker1]
        let path = UIBezierPath(
            ovalIn: CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 30.0, width: 50.0, height: 100.0)
        )
        UIColor.lightGray.setFill()
        path.fill()
        /// [marker1]
    }

    func oval2() {
        /// [marker2]
        let path = UIBezierPath(
            ovalIn: CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 150.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
        )
        UIColor.lightGray.setFill()
        path.fill()
        /// [marker2]
    }

}
```

Circle on a Simulator

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you haven't assigned a class to your custom view. So Select your view from Storyboard then follow the step shown below:

[image]

And your result will be:

[image]

Hope this will help.